# 'Printing' from a SQL 2008 R2 trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have PRINT 'something' in a trigger, where does that output go?

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It print statement will bubble up to the query that initiated the trigger to execute. From which it will return to the client, SSMS, ADO, etc.

Comment: So if a third party initiates the request, they would need to have a mechanism to view that print.  Thanks.

Comment: However, if the triggering application is unattended, like say SSIS, what is the point of a print statment? I have never seen anyone use print in a trigger.

Comment: That's part of why I asked the question.  It seems pointless most of the time to have that 'PRINT' then.  (at least for me).

Comment: In an unattended application you can use the `RAISEERROR` to trigger warnings and errors for you application to handle.

Comment: What if you don't have control of the application?  Can you dump a trigger error somewhere else?

Comment: Yes with the RAISEERROR, you can set it to log. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you run the triggering statement.  In Management Studio window, you will see the trigger output in the Messages tab.

Comment: What if it runs when no one is connect to SSMS?  Suppose I have a trigger on a table that writes to another table when a record is inserted.  A 3rd party program writes to the table.  A print statement on that trigger goes where?